# how update record from an array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a form like the following:

[image: Form]

Within this form there is a dynamic table where through jquery I can add or delete dynamic input fields.
This table records information about the tools that are used for the manufacture of a piece, then the main model is a piece and in turn, within the table these two tool entities (red color) and insert (blue color) participate

Part of my blade file (dynamic input fields)

```
 <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Herramientas</h3>               
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamicTable">              
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%">Posición</th>
                        <th width="20%">Herramienta</th>                 
                        <th width="20%">Inserto</th>                 
                        <th width="20%">Calidad</th>                       
                        <th width="5%"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></th>
                    </tr>
                    @forelse ($piece->tools as $p)  
                        <tr> 
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][position]" value="{{ $p->position }} " placeholder="Posición"  class="form-control select2" /></td>                                                 
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][code_tool]" value="{{ $p->code_tool }}"  placeholder="Herramienta"class="form-control" /></td>                        
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][code_insert]" value="{{ $p->insert->code_insert }}" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td>                       
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][quality]" value="{{ $p->insert->quality }}" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control" /></td>                      
                        </tr> 
                    @empty
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></button></td>
                    @endforelse                                     
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

to save this information I had no problems
I've solved it like this:

store method

```
  $addmore = $request->addmore;
                $arrTool = [];

                foreach($addmore as $add)
                {
                    $insert = Insert::create([
                        'code_insert' => $add['code_insert'],
                        'quality'     => $add['quality']
                    ]);  

                    $tools = $insert->tools()->create([
                        'position'   => $add['position'],
                        'code_tool'  => $add['code_tool'],                   
                        'insert_id'  => $insert->id                            
                    ]);                     

                    $arrTool[] = $tools->id;                  
                }
```

With that I keep my data from my dynamic table perfectly. Now the problem I have is that I need to update this information. So how should I recover the information iterate on these dynamic fields and update them?

I am trying this without success I am confused in this part:

update method:

```
   $piece  = Piece::findOrFail($id); 

                // $this->authorize('create', new Piece);                               
                // dd($piece);

                $addmore = $request->addmore;
                $arrTool = [];


                foreach($addmore as $add)
                {
                    $insert = Tool::where('insert_id', $piece->$id)->update([
                        'code_insert' => $add['code_insert'],
                        'quality'     => $add['quality']
                    ]);  

                    $tools = $insert->tools()->updateOrCreate([
                        'position'   => $add['position'],
                        'code_tool'  => $add['code_tool'],                   
                        'insert_id'  => $insert->id                            
                    ]);                     

                    $arrTool[] = $tools->id;                  
                }
```

I need someone to guide me on how to update these dynamic fields

**UPDATED 1**

Well, I understand, before I want to reach the situation: As a piece it is the main model, there is a relationship belongsToMany with tool, basically because a piece can have one to several tools, and the same tool can be in one to several pieces.
First, you should first look for the piece along with its associated tools through this line:

```
  $piece  = Piece::whit('tools')->findOrFail($id);
```

Now to iterate over these dynamic fields, it must be understood that within this dynamic table there is a hasMany relationship between tool and insert
My problem is here if in my store method with this I am creating:

```
 foreach($addmore as $add)
                {
                    $insert = Insert::create([
                        'code_insert' => $add['code_insert'],
                        'quality'     => $add['quality']
                    ]);
```

in my update method it doesn't allow me to do something like this:

```
 foreach($addmore as $add)
                {
                    $insert = Insert::update([
                        'code_insert' => $add['code_insert'],
                        'quality'     => $add['quality']
                    ]);
```

This is what has confused me in which way I apply logic because here I am already iterating on dynamic fields

**UPDATED 2**

I keep trying to update the tools that belong to a particular piece.
**Perform 2 types of tests.
In the first test I am creating a piece, and associating 2 new tools**, as you can see in the image it is created successfully.

[image: create_piece]

**In the second test I am updating the created part**, then I am modifying some fields of my own part and at the same time I am modifying the associated tools.
What happened?
The part was updated, that is, the part's own fields were correctly updated.
In the case of the tools instead of updating the ones that have already been created, the opposite happened, a new tool was created as you can see in the image.

[image: update_piece]

My update method looks like this:

```
                $piece  = Piece::with('tools')->findOrFail($id); 


                $addmore = $request->addmore;
                $arrTool = [];


                foreach($addmore as $add)
                {
                    $insert = Insert::where('id', $add)->updateOrCreate([
                        'code_insert' => $add['code_insert'],
                        'quality'     => $add['quality']
                    ]);  

                    $tools = $insert->tools()->updateOrCreate([
                        'position'   => $add['position'],
                        'code_tool'  => $add['code_tool'],                   
                        'insert_id'  => $insert->id                            
                    ]);                     

                    $arrTool[] = $tools->id;                  
                }
```

**Please indicate that I must modify in my method so that only the tools that were already created are updated, in my case a new tool is being created.**

model piece:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Piece extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'program_id', 'gag_id', 'denomination', 'code', 'part_piece', 'time', 'observation'
    ];    

    public function program()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
    }  

    public function gag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gag::class);
    } 

    public function tools() 
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tool::class)->withTimestamps();
    }   

}
```

model tool:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tool extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'insert_id', 'position', 'code_tool', 'type', 'category', 'status', 'description', 'reason'
    ];   


    public function insert()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Insert::class);
    } 

    public function pieces()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Piece::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

model insert:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Insert extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'code_insert', 'quality', 'type', 'category', 'status', 'description', 'reason'
    ];

    public function tools()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tool::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a mass updateOrCreate? Sadly it doesn't look like laravel's eloquent has this out of the box. There's a few [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/performant-way-to-mass-update-or-create](custom) implementations people have done though. Otherwise consider composing raw SQL statements or just looping through models.

Comment: @Gavin When you say: consider composing plain SQL statements or simply tracing the models. could you give me an example I can't understand you, it seems that I am in something I can't find a solution

Comment: @Gavin How would you apply the logic to be able to update the dynamic input fields?

Comment: iterate over the stored values, placing the key of the model into the field name, eg, if the record is 15 then the field name might be `addmore[15][position]`  Then when you get the form response you can use the key to know which record to update

Comment: @Snapey Please check my update add some details to my question, so what clarification could you give me?

Comment: There is has many from insert to tool but in your table there can only be one to one relationship?

Comment: @Snapey, please review my second update I think I will solve it with your help
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When updating delete your previous data and insert your new data again.

Only for these sections data:

[image]

Comment: please check my second update I think with your help I will solve it
thanks!